# Cacti SNMP - Getting "value: U" although there is a value available

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, cacti

I've followed the guide on the following forum to get postfix logs graphed in cacti:
http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=6657

(See the fifth post)

The installation steps on the post is as follows:

> 1) Configure SNMP agent on Mail server and make sure it is set up
>   right.
>
> 2) Unzip fetch_mail_statistics.pl script in place of your
>   choice. (I used /usr/local/bin)
>
> 3) Check that your perl path in script
>   points to perl executable
>
> 4) Add following line in snmpd.conf file
>   Code: pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255
>   /usr/local/bin/fetch_mail_statistics.pl /var/log/mail.log
>   /var/log/mailstats.db .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255
>
> 5) Adjust your maillog filename and path corresponding to your system.
>   mailstats.db are used for internal script data storage, place it
>   anywhere. 6) Import template in cacti.

When I run the following command from the terminal, I'm able to get values and graph postfix in cacti:

```
/usr/local/bin/fetch_mail_statistics.pl /var/log/mail.log /var/log/mailstats.db .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255 -g .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.9
```

Although when I added the the configuration to snmp.conf (See step 4) I'm only getting "value: U" and nAn in cacti.

I've checked permissions and I ran the script manually as the snmp-user (sudo -u snmp "code-here") without problems. We graph other stuff which works so there aren't any configuration problems with snmp or cacti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Data templates
2. Locate the Data template
3. Check that the Maximum is not set lower than the value you get.
4. If so change it to 1 trillion or any suitable max.